# Theorems without begin{} and end{}

Tags: amsthm

My question is more a curiosity than a problem.
I notice that the following text builds a valid document. I thought the only correct way to use this theorem environment would be to write the body between '\begin{definition}' and '\end{definition}'.

Why don't I get any warnings or errors?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\title{A reason to argue} 
\author{Grassy Knoll}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
Here is a weird thing:

\definition[rain] Water that falls from the sky.  
It falls from up high.

The definition does not end, so something is wrong.
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, it *seems* to work, but several things are not done (or undone) because of the missing group and execution of `\enddefinition`.

Comment: Can't test now, but there should be a warning about exiting the main file with a nest level greater than 1... I'll check tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
\begin{definition}
```

several commands are performed by `\begin`, followed by doing `\definition`.

Similarly, when LaTeX processes

```
\end{definition}
```

it executes `\enddefinition` and also several commands connected to `\end`.

If you don't use the proper `\begin{...}...\end{...}` LaTeX is left in an unpredictable state, because an environment is supposed to be processed inside a group, so many settings are automatically undone by the end of the group, which is provided by `\end`.

For instance, the font remains italic, as you perhaps discovered. And there is no vertical space after the paragraph that's supposed to be the definition text.

#### Output with your code

[image]

#### Output with the proper `\begin` and `\end`

[image]